# DropboxUnlinkedException android

Tags: android, dropbox

I'm following this tutorial on the dropbox webste.

[turorial for android dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/setup#android)

I've got the app key and secret, and placed them in my code and also in the correct place in the manifest. Also the manifest hast internet permission too.

So the set up is fine. The App is meant to upload a text file to my dropbox account. It seems to start authenticating properly but the putFile() method is throwing a DropboxUnlinkedException. When the app runs you have to allow access to your account on the phone, when i click allow the app finishes authenticating correctly. i think everything is ok apart from executing the putfile() method.

i've tried clearing the keys at the start of the app but still no luck.

i've done some logging, but not sure what to do now, anybody any ideas?

thanks matt.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI;
import com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.Entry;
import com.dropbox.client2.android.AndroidAuthSession;
import com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxException;
import com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxUnlinkedException;
import com.dropbox.client2.session.AccessTokenPair;
import com.dropbox.client2.session.AppKeyPair;
import com.dropbox.client2.session.Session.AccessType;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

public class DropboxfileuploadActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "DropboxfileuploadActivity";
    final static private String APP_KEY = "***********";
    final static private String APP_SECRET = "k3i***********";
    final static private AccessType ACCESS_TYPE = AccessType.APP_FOLDER;

    final static private String ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME = "prefs";
    final static private String ACCESS_KEY_NAME = "ACCESS_KEY";
    final static private String ACCESS_SECRET_NAME = "ACCESS_SECRET";

    private DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mDBApi;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // setContentView(R.layout.main);

        clearKeys();
        Log.e(TAG, "keys cleared");
        AppKeyPair appKeys = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
        AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeys, ACCESS_TYPE);


        mDBApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);
        mDBApi.getSession().startAuthentication(DropboxfileuploadActivity.this);
        Log.e(TAG, "started authentication");

        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        try {

            File fileToUpload = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                     +File.separator
                     +"dropboxapp"); 
                fileToUpload.mkdirs();

                Log.e(TAG, "dirs made");

            File file = new File(fileToUpload.getAbsolutePath()+"/uploadedFile.txt");
            Log.e(TAG, "the file to be uploaded has a size of "+file.length()+" bytes");

            inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            Log.e(TAG, "inputstream created");



            Entry newEntry = mDBApi.putFile("/test.txt", inputStream,
                    file.length(), null, null);
            Log.e(TAG, "putFile method executed");

            Log.i("DbExampleLog", "The uploaded file's rev is: " + newEntry.rev);
        } catch (DropboxUnlinkedException e) {
            // User has unlinked, ask them to link again here.
            Log.e("DbExampleLog", "User has unlinked.");

        } catch (DropboxException e) {
            Log.e("DbExampleLog", "Something went wrong while uploading.");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("DbExampleLog", "File not found.");
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {}
            }
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }//end of oncreate()


    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();



        if (mDBApi.getSession().authenticationSuccessful()) {
            try {
                // MANDATORY call to complete auth.
                // Sets the access token on the session
                mDBApi.getSession().finishAuthentication();

                if(mDBApi.getSession().authenticationSuccessful()){
                Log.e(TAG, "Authentication finished");
                }
                AccessTokenPair tokens = mDBApi.getSession().getAccessTokenPair();

                // Provide your own storeKeys to persist the access token pair
                // A typical way to store tokens is using SharedPreferences
                storeKeys(tokens.key, tokens.secret);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.i("DbAuthLog", "Error authenticating", e);
            }
        }


    }//end of onResume()

    private void storeKeys(String key, String secret) {
        // Save the access key for later
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
        Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.putString(ACCESS_KEY_NAME, key);
        edit.putString(ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, secret);
        edit.commit();
    }

    private void clearKeys() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
        Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.clear();
        edit.commit();
    }

}//end of class
```

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tecmark.dropboxfileupload"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".DropboxfileuploadActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
      android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard">
      <intent-filter>
        <!-- Change this to be db- followed by your app key -->
        <data android:scheme="db-3*********" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

.

```
06-03 09:54:51.117: E/DropboxfileuploadActivity(20365): started authentication
06-03 09:54:51.117: E/DropboxfileuploadActivity(20365): dirs made
06-03 09:54:51.117: E/DropboxfileuploadActivity(20365): the file to be uploaded has a size of 147 bytes
06-03 09:54:51.117: E/DropboxfileuploadActivity(20365): inputstream created
06-03 09:54:51.117: E/DbExampleLog(20365): User has unlinked.
06-03 09:54:57.397: E/DropboxfileuploadActivity(20365): Authentication finished
```

.

here's the full stack.

```
06-03 09:54:51.067: E/DropboxfileuploadActivity(20365): keys cleared
06-03 09:54:51.077: E/dalvikvm(20365): Could not find class 'org.json.simple.JSONArray', referenced from method com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.revisions
06-03 09:54:51.077: W/dalvikvm(20365): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 223 (Lorg/json/simple/JSONArray;) in Lcom/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI;
06-03 09:54:51.087: D/dalvikvm(20365): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0053
06-03 09:54:51.087: E/dalvikvm(20365): Could not find class 'org.json.simple.JSONArray', referenced from method com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.search
06-03 09:54:51.087: W/dalvikvm(20365): VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 223 (Lorg/json/simple/JSONArray;) in Lcom/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI;
06-03 09:54:51.087: D/dalvikvm(20365): VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x006d
06-03 09:54:51.117: E/DropboxfileuploadActivity(20365): started authentication
06-03 09:54:51.117: E/DropboxfileuploadActivity(20365): dirs made
06-03 09:54:51.117: E/DropboxfileuploadActivity(20365): the file to be uploaded has a size of 147 bytes
06-03 09:54:51.117: E/DropboxfileuploadActivity(20365): inputstream created
06-03 09:54:51.117: E/DbExampleLog(20365): User has unlinked.
06-03 09:54:57.397: E/DropboxfileuploadActivity(20365): Authentication finished
06-03 10:21:31.087: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(20365): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
06-03 10:21:31.087: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(20365): InputConnection = android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection@40d727e0, active client = false
```

Comment: Please add the exception here.

Comment: I thought i had in the title;) DropboxunlinkedException. if you look at the log file is says "user has unlinked". In the code the block that logs that message comes from this kind of exception. thanks

Comment: Sorry if this was unclear. What I meant was the stacktrace.

Comment: @user714965 i posted the full stack. That is all that is printed out to logcat.

Comment: Is your problem solved now? I am stuck with same issue. :(

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem.

As you have not posted the answer here, I guess the issue is still open for you.

Follow these steps: (I will just mention the extra steps that I followed)

1. Go to project's properties.
2. go to Java Build path
3. Go to Order and Export
4. Select `json_simple-1.1.jar` (right check mark will come)
5. Now select `json_simple-1.1.jar` and `dropbox-android-sdk` jar and move them `UP` by pressing **UP** button on right hand side.
6. Clean build your project.

And it's done :)